# Laravel Aimeos package pagination broken

Tags: e-commerce, laravel-6.2, aimeos

I think I am also getting the same issue.

I have imported 281 products out of 372 products manually then results showing for my category on the frontend is fine. If I inserted beyond 281 then it is showing the same error i.e.

> A non-recoverable error occurred.

then I also checked with pages 3 and 4. It is being opened but having issues with pages 1 and 2 on which it is giving errors.

[image: Category Issue Image]

Comment: "Same issue" as what? You haven't referred to anything.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.